# Where can I get my mtg-cube critiqued?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-cube

I have reached a point in my cube building process where the decisions about what cards to include are getting tough. It's no longer as simple as "Card A is better than card B. Include card A.". Now I need to think about what archetypes to support and a lot of other stuff.

Where is a good place to get my cube critiqued by other cube enthusiasts?

Comment: I didn't want to include it in my question, but here's a link to my cube: http://cubetutor.com/viewcube/2191

Comment: Just judging by your question, you might be going about it the wrong way. You might want to put the archetypes in there and then build around it. =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the MTG Salvation forum (http://forums.mtgsalvation.com/forumdisplay.php?f=349) there are several categories regarding cubes. You can post your cube list (1000+ there already) there, but also discuss cards and archetypes.

Comment: I'm already there, it's the best one I know of. Thank you. I'm looking for more :)

Answer (score 1):

The best place that I know of is http://www.reddit.com/r/mtgcube

Other options include tweeting the link to your cube with the hash tag #mtgcube.

Quite often if you do one or both of those, people will draft your cube using cubetutor, which will then give you drafting statistics about what cards are taken highest, and you'll usually get direct feedback from the person themselves as well.